# page not in open in new window

Tags: jsf, primefaces, prettyfaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 with PrettyFaces for rewrite URL in my project. I face one problem in PrettyFaces. E.g in same (same window PrettyFaces) view  open the page fine. But using menuitem click  open  page new window time page not show shown so PrettyFaces not working.
I try below code:

**prettyface.xml**

```
<url-mapping id="studenFaceId">
<pattern value="/BSCMain" />
<view-id value="/pages/bsc/bscMain.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

**javascript**

```
function NewWindow(mypage,myname)
{
params  = 'width='+screen.width;
params += ', height='+screen.height;
params += ', top=0, left=0';
params +=', scrollbars=yes';
newwin=window.open(mypage,myname, params);
if (window.focus)
{
newwin.focus()
}
return false;
}
```

**xhtml**

```
<p:menuitem id="dashBoard" ajax="false" value="student" 
onclick="return NewWindow('./../bsc/bscMain.xhtml','BSCMain');"
update="main"/>
```

My doubt I use same window prettyface work fine but in same to  open new window time prettyface not working it will shown only a empty page.

Comment: Any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: @Jasper de Vries no error show in JavaScript console

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pretty URL instead of some relative view id in your JavaScript. Something like:

```
<p:menuitem id="dashBoard" ajax="false" value="student" 
   onclick="return NewWindow('#{request.contextPath}/BSCMain','BSCMain');"
   update="main"/>
```

Comment: #{request.contextPath} use to  now page open in new window is work fine but rewrite URL is not working .I given rewrite <view-id value="/bsc/bscMain.xhtml"/> but not working i.e it show full path in url